# updateFirst method not always saving the object

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

**updateFirst** method of Spring Mongo Template is not always updating the mongo Db collection as expected.

(update request is fired by a save button in Front end ui , we see that a toast message appears saying table is successfully saved after save button is pressed and request is completed)

When few update requests are fired in sequential order one after another with no gap between updates, after few requests I can see that the data is no longer updated but there are no errors in logs.

Below is the method which updates the Database.

```
@Override
public void updateTable(Source source, Table table) {
    log.debug("updating existing table " + table.getTableId() + " on source " + source.getSourceId());
    source.setStatus(SourceStatus.InProcess);
    Query q = query(where("_id").is(source.getId()).and("deleted").is(false).and("tables._id").is(table.getId()));
    Update u = update("tables.$", table);
    u.set("lastModifiedAt", source.getLastModifiedAt()).set("lastModifiedBy",
            source.getLastModifiedBy()).set("errorInObject", source.isErrorInObject()).set(
            "errorInChildObject", source.isErrorInChildObject()).set("errors", source.getErrors()).set(
            "failedFields", source.getFailedFields()).set("status",source.getStatus());
    template.updateFirst(q, u, Source.class);
}
```

I have logged queries fired to Mongo Db on spring boot application using properties file parameter and always update query that is being fired has proper values , but

**when update works** -- There is a log message that says "Saving object to database" just before the update query is fired.

**when update does not work** -- There is a log message that says "Saving object to database" just after the update query is fired , I think its writing to DB the previous update instead of current update.

MongoDB version -- 2.6.7

Spring Mongo Template Driver version -- 2.13.3

Spring Boot version -- v1.3.2.RELEASE

Can provide additional information if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to dig deep into the issue and see that the issue occurs when I fire update commands to Db with no gap between them which some how is disrupting MongoDb's queue to process the update and some update is getting over written.

So I have added 500 ms delay to every update request before calling the updateFirst method  and this fixed the issue now the update is preserved all the times even when the update requests are very frequent there is enough time to process the update.